# c# mvc4 how to assign object of class into DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

how to assign object of class instead of string value into DropDownListFor? in below is example how to should work.

model:

```
public class Language
{
    public int Id {set; get;}
    public string Index {set; get;}
    public string Name { set; get;}  
}
```

controller:

```
public LanguageController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult show( Language lang = null )
    {
        return View( lang );
    }

    // i try something like that and dont working, 
    // that show list of language but razor form call controler method with empty parameter
    public static List<SelectListItem> ListOfLanguages()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach ( Language l in _languageRepository.Languages )
        {
            list.Add( new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = l.Index,
                Selected = false,
                Text = l.Name
            });
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

view:

```
@using( html.beginform( "show", "LanguageController" ) )
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Language, ListOfLanguages() )
    <input type="submit" >
}
```

sorry, but i dont have any idea how to explain that

Comment: Html.DropDownList("ddlBranches", (SelectList)ViewBag.ListBranches, "--Seleccionar--", new { id = "ddlBranches", class = "select" })</h3>  you  must assign ViewBag.ListBranches in controller method  ViewBag.ListBranches = new SelectList(branches, "Planta", "CiaPla", id);

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the items to the the view. one way to do is by using a view model.

```
public class ShowLanguageVm
{
  public List<SelectListItem> Languages { set;get;}
  public string Language { set;get;}
}
```

If you already have a view model for your view, simply add the `Languages` property to that.

Now in your GET action, create an object of this, Call your `ListOfLanguages` method and set the `Languages` collection. Pass the view model object to the view.

```
public ACtionResult Show(string Language ="")
{
   //to do : Do something with the value of Language  if it is not null
   var vm=new ShowLanguageVm();
   vm.Languages = ListOfLanguages();
   return View(vm);
}
```

And in the view, which is strongly typed to our ShowLanguageVm class, you can use the `Html.DropDownListFor` helper method to render the language dropdown.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Show","Language"))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.Language,Model.Languages)
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: thanks for response, but i want to keep class in parameter in Show method

Comment: in beginform i use also a other filed of Language class

Comment: You can add those needed properties to the view model.

Answer (score 0):

Your view can't access a method from the controller, this is whole idea of separation of MVC.

You need to pass the `SelectList` from the controller action to the view in one of the supported methods:

1- Through a strongly typed model, just like @Shyju showed in his answer
2- Through `ViewBag` variable which is a dynamic object that lets you set a variable with a name and use the same name in the view, ex:

```
public LanguageController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult show( Language lang = null )
    {
        ViewBag.LanguageList = ListOfLanguages();
        return View( lang );
    }

    // i try something like that and dont working, 
    // that show list of language but razor form call controler method with empty parameter
    public static List<SelectListItem> ListOfLanguages()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
        foreach ( Language l in _languageRepository.Languages )
        {
            list.Add( new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = l.Index,
                Selected = false,
                Text = l.Name
            });
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

And in your view:

```
@using( html.beginform( "show", "LanguageController" ) )
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Language, (SelectList)ViewBag.LanguageList)
    <input type="submit" >
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i did it so works, below is the solution

view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Language.Index, LabelController.ListOfLanguages())
```

controller:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListOfLanguages()
{
    var langs = _languageRepository.Languages.Select( x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = x.Index,
        Text = x.Name
    });
    return new SelectList( langs, "Value", "Text");
}

public ActionResult show( Language lang = null )
{
    lang = _languageRepository.Find(x => x.Index == label.Language.Index );        
    return View( lang );
}
```